# install python pygame on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, ubuntu-14.10

I want to install pygame library on Ubunbu 14.10. I am using Python 2.7.x. At this time I found dependences problems with python-numpy dependence., because it uses a previous version of gcc that 14.10 uses that's why I am stuck with this, my question is: is there any way to install pygame on 14.10?

best

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the terminal

type in

sudo apt-get install python-pygame

It should download and install the dependencies required for pygame.